How can i take advantage of a table partition in GCP programatically?
I'm trying to reduce the amount of processed data in a GCP query. The table that I'm querying is partitioned so if I enter the following where clause the amount of processed data is effectively reduced:
WHERE
  partition_column BETWEEN 264 AND 274

Since I don't want to hardcode the values, I'm trying to get them using subqueries or the DECLARE clause like this:
DECLARE minValue INT64;
DECLARE maxValue INT64;

SET minValue = (SELECT MIN(filter_column) FROM gcpTable);
SET maxValue = (SELECT MAX(filter_column) FROM gcpTable);

The WHERE clause looks like this
WHERE
    partition_column BETWEEN minValue AND maxValue 

The problem is whenever I try to programmatically declare the maximum and minimum values of the partition column the amount of processed data is the same as if I was not filtering at all.
Is there a way to programmatically define the values of a partition column in a GCP table so that I can take advantage of the reduced amount of data processing?
Thanks

How do you use your where? Is it in an execute immediate?

I had never used EXECUTE IMMEDIATE. It worked perfectly! thanks
